# Unable to build uri with ":" in host address for async api call

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asynchronous, uri

I am attempting to make a put call using HttpClient.PutAsync to an external api with an address that contains a ":" in the host name, e.g. "https://xx-xx-xxx:000/orders/create".

If I pass the url string directly into HttpClient.PutAsync(apiUrl, apiContent) or build a Uri to pass into it, the host name is truncated at the ":", e.g."https://xx-xx-xxxx/orders/create" . If I try forcing the ":" into the Uri using UriBuilder, it throws an exception of: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

Do I need to build a custom UriParser class to do this? If so, I am unsure of how to go about this and where to register it.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        try
        {
            //this causes exception
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder();
            builder.Scheme = "https";
            builder.Host = "xx-xx-xx00:000";
            builder.Path = "/orders/create";
            Uri apiUri = builder.Uri;

            //this gets truncated if passed into PutAsync
            string apiUrl = "https://xx-xx-xx00:000/orders/create";

            //this also truncates
            Uri uri = new Uri(apiUrl);

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedUidPwd);


            response = await client.PutAsync(apiUri, apiContent);

        }
```

EDIT: Apparently this is just for a 3 digit port number, ie "https://xx-xx-xxx:0000/orders/create" does not truncate. However, I am fairly certain the port I'm trying to access has 3 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the port number on the UriBuilder's `Port` property rather than putting it in the `Host` property. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.port?view=netframework-4.8#System_UriBuilder_Port).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that. I still received a 404 response with a message of {Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'https://xx-xx-xx00/orders/create',, Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 149
}}

Comment: @bxded Are you able to make a request via `curl` or Postman to the endpoint? That way you can compare that response with the one you mentioned here.

Comment: Postman is returning a 404 as well. I'm beginning to suspect it might be problems at the endpoint. But that still doesn't explain the odd 3 digit port truncation (see my edit to the question)

Comment: @bxded Well at least you know that your call seems to work as expected now. The 3-digit port truncation is a bit odd though...

Comment: the truncation might be because any port below 1024 is a well-known port:  "The port numbers in the range from 0 to 1023 (0 to 210 − 1) are the well-known ports or system ports.[2] They are used by system processes that provide widely used types of network services. On Unix-like operating systems, a process must execute with superuser privileges to be able to bind a network socket to an IP address using one of the well-known ports": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers